# Unable to find dependency 'SYSTEM. DATA. ODBC' when creating MSI

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, windows-installer, nuget-package

I have a WinForms type project in .NET Standard 2.0. I want to make an msi file for in the testing environment.

However, when I compile the source project (WinForms) everything goes well.

When I build the project that generates the msi, I get the error:

> Unable to find dependency 'SYSTEM. DATA. ODBC' (Signature-'B03F5F7F11D50A3A' Version-'0.0.0.0') of assembly 'GenericDataAccess'.

I checked where I use the Nuget package called SYSTEM. DATA. ODBC and I saw that its dependencies nuget.org are NET Standard 2.0. It also supports NET Framework 4.7.2. So, I tried to downgrade the component to this version to see if that worked. But when I downgrade it, I get the following error when trying to build the MSI file:

> Unable to find dependency 'SYSTEM. Diagnostics. TRACING' (Signature-'B03F5F7F11D50A3A' Version-'0.0.0.0') of assembly 'netstandard.dll'

And that's not the only dependency that fails. How can I validate dependencies to prevent compilation errors?

Comment: What is your type of the installer project? Did your project target to `net472`? Also, which version of `System.Data.Odbc` nuget package did you use?

Comment: `I have a WinForms type project in .NET Standard 2.0.` What does it mean? a net framework project that depends on a net standard lib project? Or anything else? Please provide more detailed info.

Comment: The installation project type is Visual Studio Installer:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects

The project went to net48.

The ODBC version is 4.7.0.

Comment: It is a Windows Forms project that has a dependency on another class library-type project built by me. This class library uses version 4.7.0 of the System.Data.ODBC library.

Comment: 1)add `<PropertyGroup><RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle></PropertyGroup>`  in the `xxx.csproj` file of your winform project and then rebuild your winform project.   2) right-click on your installer project-->`Add`-->`Project Output`-->select your winform project and `Locally-Copied Items`. Also, you can enter `Add`->`Assembly` to add `System.Data.Odbc.dll` into installer project.